# How to do BLE multi-advertisement from single iOS app?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral

I am working on one iOS app in which I need to do multi-advertisement of BLE. I created two instance of `CBPeripheralManager` and tried to advertise two different advertisement packet simultaneously, but its not working.

Can somebody suggest any method to do this task. From another central (scanner) app, I should get two different advertisement.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: You will just have a single CBPeripheralManager instance and call `addService` multiple times

Comment: @Paulw11 but that will show single advertisement with multiple services. I want that on other device, it should appear as if advertisement is coming from two different devices. Android support multi - advertisement. I have to implement same in iOS.

Comment: You only have one phone so you only have one device

Comment: @Paulw11 In android, different apps on same device can advertise their own advertisement individually. And on android we are able to send different advertisement from same app also. Similar thing I have to implement on iOS.

Comment: You can't on iOS. Different apps can advertise different services but all services are offered by the same peripheral device

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for reply.. I have one more question. If different apps wants to advertise different UUID's in advertisement packet, then in limited 28-38 bytes, how those UUID's will accommodate. Sorry, I am new to iOS platform.

Comment: iOS will send multiple advertisements as required. Best practice is for each app to only advertise its primary service. Secondsry services can be discovered once a connection is made

Comment: @Paulw11 If 4 apps are simultaneously advertising on one iPhone, then one advertisement packet will not be able to accommodate all the primary services of different apps. So in this case, if I am scanning for particular UUID using scanForPeripheralWithServices, will I be able to scan any of the four UUID?

Comment: Yes. iOS can simply alternate the services contained in each advertising packet it sends